# Customers are counted as "exits" when they get redirected to Stripe for payment, then as "entrances" when brought back to my thank you page

Tags: google-analytics, payments

I've got Stripe [checkout sessions](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions) set-up on a custom e-commerce site in order to accept payments. This integration is different to the old Stripe Checkout system, where an iframe popped within your page to ask for credit card details. In the new system, you get redirected to the Stripe domain.

When users are redirected to the Stripe domain (https://checkout.stripe.com), they are counted as exits in my Google Analytics data.

They then get counted as entrances when they land on the "thank you" page, which is how I track my conversions.

This is preventing me from analyzing the full conversion funnel, as all my customers seem to be entering the site from "checkout.stripe.com".

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add stripe to the referrer exclusion list in Google Analytics.  See [Referral exclusions - Analytics Help](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en).

The list can be edited in your Google Analytics settings.  When a domain is on the exclusion list, GA will not start a new session when it sees it in a referral.  The list is meant for cases just like this where you send the visitor away and expect them to come back.

Comment: Oh thanks. But will this also prevent people leaving the site from being counted as exits ? I'm trying this out now :)

Comment: Yes.  "Exit" means "last page of the session".  When the session is continued when they get back it prevents the exit as well.

Comment: After verification, this does indeed work correctly ! I'm accepting it as a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to set up [cross domain measurement](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034148?hl=en) as it is used for the exact situation that you describe.

I'm not sure if Stripe will let you add a your GA/GTM snippet to your checkout page, but I suspect they probably will, the documentation linked above and the related pages will tell you how to set this up.

Comment: Isn't cross-domain measurement meant to be used when you control these domains ? Like if you go from "mybrand.com" to "mybrand-checkout.com" ?

Comment: If it works for your situation (basically, if you can add your GA snippet to the checkout pages), then it'll be the best option for you because you'll get full GA data. If it won't then you'll need to do referral exclusions. The specifics of your implementation will determine if it's possible or not.